# Offline DataBinding = enable leads to Error: Could not find databinding-runtime.jar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I am trying to make databinding work with **local** dependencies repo.
I have Android Support Repo downloaded.

When I enable databinding with

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
            }
```

I got this error:

```
Could not find databinding-runtime.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.5.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/User/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/androidx/databinding/databinding-runtime/3.5.1/databinding-runtime-3.5.1.jar
```

I have databinding-runtime-3.5.1.**aar** not `.jar` in my local repo.
How to make Gradle be happy with `.aar`?

my build.gradle: https://pastebin.com/xTFNg9MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After eating ton of shit with local maven repository I realized that Gradle was never ment to work offline.
SOME third-party libraries like RxJAva can be added manually, but most of them will not work.
So the answer is: sync your  Grandle online or find another job.